# accessing an object key name in an ionic view

Tags: ionic-framework, javascript-objects

I am trying to retrieve a userId which is stored in the key name of an object :
{userID:{firstname:foo, lastname:bar}}

I am doing this from an ionic view :

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="x in people" class="item item-icon-right" 
ui-sref="app.people.profile({userId: x.howdoIextractmykeyname"})  >
```

I tried using this to extract the key name :
Object.keys(myVar)[0]

ie:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="x in people" class="item item-icon-right" 
ui-sref="app.people.profile({userId: Object.keys(x)[0]"})  >
```

but this does not seem to work

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just figured out how to do this :

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="(key,value) in people"
    class="item item-icon-right" ui-sref="app.people.profile({userId: key})"
    >
```